# Prover9 "Some, but not all, of the requested proofs were found"

Tags: logic, theorem-proving

I'm running some lattice proofs through Prover9/Mace4. Prover9's saying `Exit: Time limit.` plus the message in the Title.

I've doubled the time limit from 60 to 120 seconds. Same message (in twice the time). The weird thing is:

- there's only one statement to prove. That is, only one `label(goal)` in the report (what's with the `but not all`?)
- it does seem to have completed the proof, in that it shows last line `$F.`
- Mace4 can't find any counter-examples (I upped its time to 120 seconds).

I've found some GHits for that message, but they seem to be all in Chinese(?)

It's possible the axioms I've given are (mutually) recursive -- I'm trying to introduce a function and a nominated 'absorbing element' [**]; and that solving will need infinitary unification. Does Prover9 do that?

I'm happy to add the axioms and goal to this message. (I'm using a non-standard way to define the meet and join.) But first, are there any sanity checks I should go through?

[**] the absorbing element is neither lattice top nor lattice bottom; more like lattice left-corner. (The element will be lattice bottom just in case the lattice degenerates to two elements.) The function is a partial ordering 'at right angles' to top/bottom. The lattice I expect to be neither complemented nor distributive (again except when 2 elements).

Comment: Prover9 proves by contradiction, so $F indicates that a contradiction has gotten found, thus indicating that a proof exists.

Can you post exactly what you gave Prover9, including the goals and assumptions?

Comment: See the answer I posted, thanks @Doug and apologies for the false alarm. I think it was nothing to do with the specific assumptions/goals.

Comment: Btw, is there a reason to use Prover9? Since the death of Bill McCune in 2009, it has not been developed further anymore. There's [E Prover](https://wwwlehre.dhbw-stuttgart.de/~sschulz/E/E.html) and [Vampire](https://github.com/vprover/vampire/) for example.

Comment: Is there a reason _not_ to use Prover9? It works (for my purposes). Logic is eternal. Why would I want something "developed further"?

Comment: Reasons against using EProver or Vampire: see their download pages; not available for Windows; in fact they don't seem to be aware of Windows as a platform. I don't want to stuff around compiling software in a UNIX environment; I want to run proofs. I'll look again when they're ready for primetime.

Comment: Prover 9 is a fine solver, it might just time out on larger problems (in particular those with equality, due to Prover 9 not being based on the superposition calculus). If you want to check your problem against a set of solvers online, you can also use [System on TPTP](http://tptp.org/cgi-bin/SystemOnTPTP).

Comment: Btw regarding primetime: E and Vampire are the state of the art provers of their field, that's why i mentioned them.

Comment: "Prover 9 not being based on the superposition calculus" hmm? Prover9's manual/glossary mentions superposition, and here https://www.cs.unm.edu/~mccune/prover9/manual/2009-11A/inf-rules.html cites both Bachmair-Ganziger-res and Nieuwenhuis-Rubio-res, both from 2001 Handbook.

Comment: Prover 9 does paramodulation, the hand book writes " Unlike the inference rule superposition, this inference rule goes into "light" sides of equations.". It does ordered resolution but that's why I pointed to equality reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

I've reproduced this after much trying, but only by setting some strange option that I'm sure I wouldn't have touched. (The only option I usually change is the `Time limit`, and I `Reset to defaults` quite often, so that would have blatted any evidence.)

Here's my guess for what happened.

> what's with the `but not all`?

- You can enter multiple goals (providing they're all positive). [**]
- With strange option settings, if Prover9 can prove the first but not the second, it'll keep trying until exhausted; but then only report the successful one -- with a `$F.` result OK.
- If you double the Time limit, it'll still prove the first and still keep on trying for the second -- taking twice the time for the same outcome.
- Mace4 will come across the first goal, and use up its time trying for a counter-example. There isn't one because it's provable. Again, doubling its Time limit will get the same outcome after twice as long.

[Note **] It's never that I intend to set multiple goals; but when I'm hacking/experimenting with axioms, I keep all the goals in the `Goals:` box so I can easily toggle un/comment. I guess I didn't comment-out one when I was uncommenting another.

The behaviour usually, as described in the manual, is Prover9 reports success at the first goal it proves; doesn't go on to other goals. If there's multiple provable goals, it seems to choose the easiest/quickest(?) irrespective of position in the file.

But with [`max_proofs` set to more than default 1](https://www.cs.unm.edu/~mccune/prover9/manual/2009-11A/goals.html#max_proofs), Prover9 will keep trying. (There's also a `auto_denials` flag that has something to do with it I don't understand.)

I've no idea how I set `max_proofs` -- I didn't recognise the `Options/Limits` sub-screen when I eventually found it. Weird.

Comment: In general, try to have only one conjecture - theorem provers disagree on how to handle them (conjunction vs disjunction) such that the TPTP standard ended up only defining semantics for a single conjecture.

Comment: Moreover, TPTP has a concept of include files that you can share a common axiom set if you want to prove multiple conjectures.

Comment: Yes I do aim to have one goal. On this occasion I messed up.